# Заменить NOT EXIST на JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть код запроса :

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(res.RANK) DESC, res.OBJ_PK) AS RowNumber, 
                    res.OBJ_SCOPE,                  
                    res.OBJ_PK,
                    MAX(res.RANK)       AS SCORE,               
                    SUM(res.MASK)       AS MASK                                                             
            FROM    RESULT  AS res              

            WHERE   
                NOT EXISTS ( SELECT DocumentMatch.OBJ_PK
                                  FROM   DocumentMatch
                                 WHERE  DocumentMatch.OBJ_PK = res.OBJ_PK
                                 AND    DocumentMatch.OBJ_SCOPE = res.OBJ_SCOPE
                               )
            AND
            (@IS_TAGS_SEARCH_USED = 'F'
                OR
            (@IS_TAGS_SEARCH_USED = 'T' AND res.MASK <> 2))         

            GROUP BY res.OBJ_SCOPE, res.OBJ_PK

            UNION ALL

            SELECT  1 AS RowNumber,
                    OBJECT_SCOPE,
                    OBJECT_PK,
                    SCORE,
                    MASK
            FROM    DocumentMatch
```

Из-за NOT EXISTS выборка отрабатывает довольно долго.

Вопрос: как правильно поменять NOT EXISTS на JOIN в данном примере?

Comment: @Mike, наличие нескольких записей будет влиять, если нужно переписать EXISTS на JOIN. Поскольку речь о NOT EXISTS - нам требуются только записи, где нет ни одной удовлетворяющей условию строки в присоединенной таблице - переписать можно без проблем, насколько я понял.

Comment: @minamoto Да, согласен, для NOT действительно без разницы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что вряд ли запрос отрабатывает долго именно из-за not exists. Обычно этот вариант более быстр, чем join из-за особенностей выполнения. Возможно, проблема в отсутствии индексов на поля соединения таблиц.

Но для join этот запрос тоже можно переписать, если я нигде не ошибся, это будет так выглядеть:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(res.RANK) DESC, res.OBJ_PK) AS RowNumber, 
                    res.OBJ_SCOPE,                  
                    res.OBJ_PK,
                    MAX(res.RANK)       AS SCORE,               
                    SUM(res.MASK)       AS MASK                                                             
            FROM    RESULT  AS res              
                    LEFT JOIN DocumentMatch
                           ON DocumentMatch.OBJ_PK = res.OBJ_PK
                           AND DocumentMatch.OBJ_SCOPE = res.OBJ_SCOPE
            WHERE   
                DocumentMatch.OBJ_PK is null
            AND
            (@IS_TAGS_SEARCH_USED = 'F'
                OR
            (@IS_TAGS_SEARCH_USED = 'T' AND res.MASK <> 2))         

            GROUP BY res.OBJ_SCOPE, res.OBJ_PK
```